# Batch file to compress all folders/files and send through mail

Tags: email, batch-file, zip

I need to create a batch file that will compress and zip all the files and folders in folder.
Once the the files and folders are zipped, the `.zip` file should be sent by **email**.

I am using **Windows 7**.

I dont have any idea about batch scripting. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would depend on which operating system the script will run on, but you didn't even provide that.

You don't say if you are knowledgeable about any languages like C# or Java or Python, but I'd recommend writing the app in something like that.  There are lots of libraries to help you with zipping, threading, etc.  You might find it easier if you open up your restriction on languages.

But, if you must, here's a solution that might help you:

https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili

Comment: i need batch file for windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You can use [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) for the zip functionality. Using its [command line options](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples) you can create a batch file.

With regards to emails, if you really have to do it in batch then you will need a 3rd party tool, or a command line tool.

A quick google revealed [this](http://www.exclamationsoft.com/exclamationsoft/netmailbot/help/examples/default.asp) site which even has batch examples.